# ImageView inside scroll View is not working

Tags: xml

I have a XML file where I want the imageView to be inside a scroll wheel but when I try to put the android:src="" attribute to the imageView element the app crashes. Can someone help me figure out what's happening in my code.

Honestly I want to make a functionality that when a button is pressed it will load a series of imageView into the scrollView and then the user can scroll through the list of imageViews that are displayed. But just for trial and error purposes I'm trying to implement this only on one single imageView so that I don't get confused when there will be a lots of them. But it's working.

Below is my activity_chapter1.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Chapter1"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/Chp1_button1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Go to Main Menu"
       android:padding="20dp"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Chp1_button1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chap11_btn"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Chap 1.1 Definition" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chap12_btn"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Chap 1.2 Explanation" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chap13_btn"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Chap 1.3 Hello World" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chap14_btn"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Chap 1.4 Hello World" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tableLayout1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src = "@drawable/a951ad1201c7bd1a758b5acfeea33fce_0"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Chp2_button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to End"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to put imageView inside scrollView with a LinearLayout but when trying to add the src attribute to the imageView the app crashes. I think it's got to do with the imageSize. But I tried also that it didn't work.